# Why can't I use arrow keys in terminal on Debian 6? (nonroot)

Tags: shell, debian, users

When I am on a non-root user I cannot use <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to list my previous commands, and if I am typing I can't use <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to say, add in a directory or to correct the spelling.

Worse, I can't use <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I could write `/var/www/mylongsitena` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not autocomplete it.

It's *extremely* annoying. How can I change this? IIRC Debian etch and lenny didn't do this. How can I unto this change?

Comment: Does this happen with a _new_ non-root test user?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation or an upgrade? Can you try creating a new user, and see if these things work.

Comment: @mattdm: I am still fairly noob. i did su irc and tested it. So i suppose it happens on ALL non root users? @Tshepang: fresh install. and this happens to users i created last week and a few weeks ago

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to have `/bin/sh` as the login shell of your non-root user, and `/bin/sh` point to dash. Dash is a shell designed to execute shell scripts that stick to standard constructs with low resource consumption. The alternative is bash, which has more programming features and interactive features such as command line history and completion, at the cost of using more memory and being slightly slower.

Change your login shell to a good interactive shell. On the command line, run

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

(You can use `/bin/bash` if you prefer.) Configure your user management program to use that different shell as the default login shell for new users (by default, the usual command-line program `adduser` uses `/bin/bash`).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue in Debian Wheezy.

Went to the Preferences/System Settings panel.
In "Keyboard", in the "Shortcuts" tab, I found under the "Windows" entry
that SUPER+Up was mapped to "Maximize window", and
SUPER+Down was mapped to 'Restore window".

I highlighted the line and pressed the backspace key to clear this shortcut
Did it for both shortcuts
This solved the problem

Comment: While this might somehow affect the up and down arrow keys (shouldn't though, unless "super" (windows) key is "stuck"), it certainly couldn't cause tab and left/right arrow keys from working properly.

Comment: Maybe it's because I am using a VNC connection (RealVNC 5.2.3 for windows 64 bits), so it could be that the "super" key is not handled correctly in the client or the VNC server.

Comment: OK, by googling even more I found that this is effectively a bug in the vnc server. [See bug 679543 at debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679543) .