# TAB autocomplete on sudo sh

Tags: shell, sudo, autocomplete

When I say `sudo sh`, <kbd>TAB</kbd> stops working as autocomplete signal on my Debian.
How can I enable <kbd>TAB</kbd> key autocomplete after I say `sudo sh` ?

Comment: What does "stops working" mean exactly? `sudo sh /` + TAB does not result in path autocomplete? What is the output of `complete -p sudo`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/why-cant-i-use-arrow-keys-in-terminal-on-debian-6-nonroot

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean after you [*typed* `sudo sh` and pressed TAB](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76669/3645), or *executed* `sudo sh` and pressed TAB ([`sh` may not load autocomplete configuration when starting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76658/3645)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying using `sudo bash` instead of `sudo sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing `complete -cf sudo`. If it works, you can just add it to your `.bashrc` file.